# resizing overlapping buttons in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

thanks all in advance for the help.
I made a 100% flash background stretch...this is main.as's  code:

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


public class Main extends MovieClip

{
    public function Main()
    {
        init();

        checkResize();

    clip_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, siteNav1);

    clip_amministra.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, siteNav2);


    clip_chisiamo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, siteNav4);

    }

    function siteNav1(e:MouseEvent):void {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.amicolibro.org/index.php"), "_self");

    }

    function siteNav2(e:MouseEvent):void {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.amicolibro.org/log-in-amministratore.php"), "_self");

    }


    function siteNav4(e:MouseEvent):void {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.amicolibro.org/chi-siamo.php"), "_self");

    }                           

    private function init():void
    {
        stage.frameRate=31;

        bg_mc.x=0;
        bg_mc.y=0;
        bg_mc.width=stage.stageWidth;
        bg_mc.height=stage.stageHeight;

        clip_mc.x=stage.stageWidth/6.3;
        clip_mc.y=stage.stageHeight/2.2;

        clip_amministra.x=stage.stageWidth/1.3;
        clip_amministra.y=stage.stageHeight/2;


              clip_chisiamo.x=stage.stageWidth/10;
        clip_chisiamo.y=stage.stageHeight/1.19; 

    }

    private function checkResize():void
    {
        stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeStage);
    }

    private function resizeStage(event:Event):void 
    {
        init();
    }

}
}
```

is it possible a proportional resizing of the buttons clip_mc, clip_amministra, clip_chisiamo ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a way to resize your objects if they are too close together or overlapping?

Here is one possible way you could go about this.  There are better ways that are more work but this is the simplest.

Do a simple relative size.  This would not be very precise, but would be very quick and may work for your needs.  Let's say 400x500 (as an example, adjust those values until you get the right amount) is the smallest the stage can go at the native button size before they start to overlap, then use this as your init() method (along with the two new global :

```
    private function init():void
    {
        var minWidth:Number = 400; //change this number to be whatever works best
        var minHeight:Number = 500; //change this number to be whatever works best

        stage.frameRate=31;

        bg_mc.x=0;
        bg_mc.y=0;
        bg_mc.width=stage.stageWidth;
        bg_mc.height=stage.stageHeight;

        clip_mc.x=stage.stageWidth/6.3;
        clip_mc.y=stage.stageHeight/2.2;

        clip_amministra.x=stage.stageWidth/1.3;
        clip_amministra.y=stage.stageHeight/2;

        clip_chisiamo.x=stage.stageWidth/10;
        clip_chisiamo.y = stage.stageHeight / 1.19; 

    //this is the new stuff
        var scaleAmount:Number = 1;
        if (stage.stageWidth < minWidth || stage.stageHeight < minHeight) {
            if (minWidth / stage.stageWidth < minHeight / stage.stageHeight) {
                scaleAmount = (minWidth / stage.stageWidth);
            }else{
                scaleAmount = minHeight / stage.stageHeight;
            }
        }

        //do this for all your buttons scaleX and scaleY properties, i'm assuming clip_mc, clip_amministra and clip_chisiamo are some of your button instances.
        clip_mc.scaleX = scaleAmount;
        clip_mc.scaleY = scaleAmount;

        clip_amministra.scaleX = scaleAmount;
        clip_amministra.scaleY = scaleAmount;

        clip_chisiamo.scaleX = scaleAmount;
        clip_chisiamo.scaleY = scaleAmount;
    }
```

Comment: So your looking for a way to make your buttons smaller only if they start to overlap?

Comment: when i have a screen resolution lower than 1920x1080 ....if i don't resize the button-links......yeah they start to overlap
i need some precise information:

1-..then use this in your init() method:

i must add your script inside here?

private function init():void
    {
        stage.frameRate=31;

        bg_mc.x=0;
        // etc..
       
        if(stage.stageWidth < 400 || stage.stageHeight < 500){//etc.etc..
    }  2-i don't know how to do this:

...//set all your buttons to have a scaleX/Y of 1.

  clip_mc.scaleX = 1;
  clip_mc.scaleY = 1;

is it right?

merci beaucoup

Comment: I updated the code to include your whole init() function, hopefully it's clearer that way.

Comment: thanks for your kind answer I tried a lot...500x400....100x2000...200x100 etc..etc..but when i use a screen resolution lower than 1920x1080 (that's my screen resolution) the buttons don't have a proportional scaling relative to the background (in the code it is the MovieClip bg_mc)..in other words...if i use a lower resolution than 1920x1080 the MovieClip bg_mc scales without distortion while the buttons don't scale in relation to the background and they overlap   thanks

Answer (score 0):

i solved in this way:

package {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


public class Main extends MovieClip

{
    public function Main()
    {
        init();

        resizeHandler();

        checkResize();

    clip_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, siteNav1); 

    clip_amministra.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, siteNav2);

    clip_chisiamo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, siteNav4);


    }

    function siteNav1(e:MouseEvent):void {                                       
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.amicolibro.org/index.php"), "_self");

    }

    function siteNav2(e:MouseEvent):void {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.amicolibro.org/log-in-amministratore.php"), "_self");

           }

    function siteNav4(e:MouseEvent):void {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.amicolibro.org/chi-siamo.php"), "_self");

    }


    private function init():void
    {
        stage.frameRate=31;

        bg_mc.x=0;                           
        bg_mc.y=0;
        bg_mc.width=stage.stageWidth;
        bg_mc.height=stage.stageHeight;

        clip_mc.x=stage.stageWidth/6.3;  
        clip_mc.y=stage.stageHeight/2.2;  

        clip_amministra.x=stage.stageWidth/2.7; 
        clip_amministra.y=stage.stageHeight/4.9; 


            clip_chisiamo.x=stage.stageWidth/10;
        clip_chisiamo.y=stage.stageHeight/1.19;

        }       


    private function resizeHandler(event:Event=null):void  //resize buttons

          {

           var sw:Number = stage.stageWidth;
           var sh:Number = stage.stageHeight;



          clip_mc.width = sw /8;         // clip_mc is 1/8 as wide as the stage..can change this number to be whatever works best
      clip_mc.height = sh /8;    // clip_mc is 1/8 as high as the stage..can change this number to be whatever works best

          clip_amministra.width = sw /10;     // clip_amministra is 1/10 as wide as the stage..can change this number to be whatever works best
      clip_amministra.height = sw /10;    // clip_amministra is 1/10 as high as the stage..can change this number to be whatever works best


      clip_chisiamo.width = sw /6;        //clip_chisiamo is 1/6 as wide as the stage..can change this number to be whatever works best
      clip_chisiamo.height = sh /6;     // clip_chisiamo is 1/6 as high as the stage..can change this number to be whatever works best



      clip_mc.scaleX <= clip_mc.scaleY ? (clip_mc.scaleX = clip_mc.scaleY) : (clip_mc.scaleY = clip_mc.scaleX); // keeps clip_mc proportional 

      clip_amministra.scaleX <= clip_amministra.scaleY ? (clip_amministra.scaleX = clip_amministra.scaleY) : (clip_amministra.scaleY = clip_amministra.scaleX); // keeps clip_amministra proportional

      clip_chisiamo.scaleX <= clip_chisiamo.scaleY ? (clip_chisiamo.scaleX = clip_chisiamo.scaleY) : (clip_chisiamo.scaleY = clip_chisiamo.scaleX); // keeps clip_chisiamo proportional


                 }

      private function checkResize():void
    {
        stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeStage);
    }

      private function resizeStage(event:Event):void 
    {
        init();
    }
    }
}
```

thanks